# SPINNER XAMARIN.ANDROID

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-spinner

Im looking for a spinnerexample that include key/value like DisplayMember/ValueMember like Winforms.
im Usign Xmarin.Android in Visual Studio 2017/2015, i being use this to populate, but it only contains MembersValue

```
<string-array>
    <ítem>ITEM 1</ítem>
</string-array>
```

and i looking for some like:

```
<string-array>
<ítem value=1>ITEM 1</ítem>
</string-array>
```

where i can get the tag valuein the method click from a buttoncontrol like this:

```
private void btnButton(Object sender,EventArgs e)

{
   string strValue=spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Actual Result  : ITEM 1

Expected Result: 1

I was trying with a dictionary as show below:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(1, "Tarjeta1");
        dict.Add(2, "tarjeta2");
```

and then Add as resource in the spinner:

```
spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(Spinner1_ItemSelected);    
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem,dict.Values.ToArray());
adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

But when i trying to get the values, it displays: Tarjeta1 or Tarjeta2 instead 1 or 2

I hope anyone can support me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use baseAdapter, watch video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o5R4qvJXZM

Or simply if your spinner items text restricted to prefix or suffix words you can extract the numeric value you want from it

```
private void btnButton(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(spinner.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("Tarjeta", string.Empty).Trim());
   string strValue = intValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Thank you very much! i was on my vacation , is for that , im couldn't   answer you quickly.